# Julia: Return early from pmap()

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

Say I have something like the following:

```
function f(x)
  some_test ? true : false
end
```

If I do `pmap(f,some_array)` I'll get some array of Bools. I'd like to do something if `contains(==,p,false)`. However, I'd like to do this thing if there is at least just one `false`. I.e. if `some_array` is very very large I would like `pmap` to stop once it finds its first `false`.

`some_test` may be quite involved so I've read that a parallel for loop is not the way to go.

E.g if I have

```
p = pmap(f,some_array,[N for i = 1:some_large_value])
if contains(==,p,false)
    return false
else
    return true
end
```

and a `false` appears when `i=100`, how can I stop `pmap` from checking `101:some_large_value`?

As another example of the behavior I'd like to do, take this example from `?pmap`.

```
julia> pmap(x->iseven(x) ? error("foo") : x, 1:4; on_error=ex->0)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 0
 3
 0
```

Instead of `on_error=ex->0` I'd like `pmap` to `return` on the first even. Something like

```
pmap(x->iseven(x) ? return : x, 1:4)
```

which would ideally result in only a `1-element Array{Int64,1}`.

Comment: This is the third time I've seen a question/request for this pattern. At one time this was my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428477/julia-parallel-for-loop-with-return-statement/43545623#43545623. Perhaps it could help somehow.

Comment: @DanGetz I've seen that post and modeled my first attempt after it. However, the work that `f` does on `some_array` can vary substantially. This leads to slow behavior of `@parallel` since all the workers are tied to the slowest. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846838/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-parallel-and-pmap?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally hard to do, since other tasks may have already started. If you're not that worried about doing a few extra runs, one way is to modify the `pmap` example from the [parallel computing docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing)

```
function pmap_chk(f, lst)
    np = nprocs()  # determine the number of processes available
    n = length(lst)
    results = Vector{Any}(n)

    i = 0
    nextidx() = (i+=1; i)

    done = false
    isdone() = done
    setdone(flag) = (done = flag)

    @sync begin
        for p=1:np
            if p != myid() || np == 1
                @async begin
                    while !isdone()
                        idx = nextidx()
                        if idx > n
                            break
                        end
                        r, flag = remotecall_fetch(f, p, lst[idx])
                        results[idx] = r
                        if flag
                            setdone(flag)
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    resize!(results, i)
end
```

Here `f` should return a tuple containing the result and whether or not it is done, e.g.

```
julia> pmap_chk(1:100) do f
       r = rand()
       sleep(r)
       (r, r>0.9)
       end
15-element Array{Any,1}:
 0.197364 
 0.60551  
 0.794526 
 0.105827 
 0.612087 
 0.170032 
 0.8584   
 0.533681 
 0.46603  
 0.901562 
 0.0894842
 0.718619 
 0.501523 
 0.407671 
 0.514958
```

Note that it doesn't stop immediately.